# How best to maintain a recent bash version on amazon linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bash, yum, amazon-linux

I require Bash 4.2 or higher. Amazon Linux default repositories only provide Bash 4.1. I have done some searches and can not find a yum repository for recent versions of Bash. I don't want to compile from source, because I want to outsource keeping abreast of bug fixes (such as [Shellshock](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/26/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-shellshock-bash-flaws/)).

I am looking for either a yum repo I can install for recent Bash binaries, or another workable way to keep a recent version of Bash on the server.

This is yum output on one of the nodes in question:

```
[ec2-user@nodeX ~]$ sudo yum install bash
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
33 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package bash-4.1.2-15.23.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Note this is a crosspost of my [previous question on the "Unix and Linux" Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172363/bash-4-3-yum-repository-for-amazon-linux).

Comment: Create your own repo from source? Pay someone to maintain a repo for you?

Comment: Are you sure that shellshock patches haven't been back ported to the version you have?

Comment: Please don't crosspost. If necessary, flag for migration.

Comment: @Sven I didn't know there was such a thing as migration, but now, reading up on it, it doesn't look very useful. Firstly, it requires a high reputation user, and second, it erases existing answers, and there's a useful answer (though not an acceptable answer) on the first post.

Comment: @Hyppy actually the current version is patched. Shellshock is an example supporting the reason not to compile from source, which is that there could be future vulnerabilities, and there is no one on the team being paid to keep on top of patches.

Comment: @lVlint67 Yum repositories are set-it-and-forget-it solutions, and though your suggestions are good, they require a lot more investment of either time or money.

Comment: @TravisWellman: If you use the `flag` function, you can notify a moderator to do this for you. Answers get migrated as well and aren't lost. And it *is* useful because crossposts are explicitly not welcome on the SE network.

Comment: "Yum repositories are set-it-and-forget-it solutions" vs "and there is no one on the team being paid to keep on top of patches.".... I guess I don't understand what you expect. If the delay between release upstream and propagation down to your repo is too long to be acceptable it is customary to take actions to resolve that issue. EG: maintain the repo yourself, compile from source, or pay someone to maintain the repo...

Comment: @sven the FAQ I read yesterday said answers are lost. Well, I'll try migration next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new Amazon Linux 2 at https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/ which comes standard with 4.2.

```
$ bash --version

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-koji-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, 4+ years later, this is still the exact same version of Bash available on AWS's latest Linux images.  So no namerefs from 4.3, no improvements from 4.4., 5.0, 5.1...  Guess we're building from source!

Comment: Amazon Linux 2022 includes version 5.1.8-2.amzn2022.0.1 per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2022/release-notes/all-packages-al2022-20221103.html

Comment: "2022" as of May certainly didn't, but I'm glad that later 2022 releases will!  It's good to see them finally update the core tools.  Thank you!